# SwiftUI ForEach asks that items are Hashable and Equatable for some reason?

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

I am following the CS193P Stanford class, in which we are supposed to build a `ForEach` view with an array of `Cards`, defined in this struct :

```
struct MemoryGame<CardContent> {
    private(set) var cards : [Card]
    
    init(pairCount : Int, createCardContent : (Int) -> CardContent){
        cards = []
        for i in 0 ..< pairCount {
            let content = createCardContent(i)
            cards.append(Card(content : content, id : i*2))
            cards.append(Card(content : content, id : i*2 + 1))
        }
    }
    
    func choose(_ card: Card) {
        
    }
    
    struct Card : Identifiable {
        var isFaceUp : Bool = true
        var isMatched : Bool = false
        var content : CardContent
        var id: Int
    }
}
```

As you can see, this struct conforms to the `Identifiable` protocol, which according to the documentation should be enough for it to work in a `ForEach` (Provided the type of `id` is `Hashable`, which `Int` is)

Yet I get the following error :

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'MemoryGame<String>.Card' conform to 'Hashable'
```

Why is it asking that ? The only thing the docs say is that the type of `id` should be `Hashable`, nothing about the entire struct being Hashable

The error hints also want me to add `Equatable` but I can't seem to understand why, there is no reported error linked to that

*NB : I am building in XCode 13 on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 with iOS 15 as a target*

---

Here is then the ViewModel code for `EmojiMemoryGame` :

```
class EmojiMemoryGame {
    static let emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    private(set) var model = MemoryGame<String>(pairCount: 4) {i in emojis[i]}
    
    var cards: Array<MemoryGame<String>.Card> {
        model.cards
    }
}
```

And the `ContentView` :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let viewModel : EmojiMemoryGame
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns : [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum : 65))]) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in // Error happens here
                        CardView(card)
                            .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show _how_ you are using your struct in `ForEach`?

Comment: I hope you are not doing `id: \.self` in your ForEach

Comment: I am not using \.self, adding the foreach code to the post...

Comment: What is your `CardContent`? I suspect it needs to be `Identifiable` as well.

Comment: @Yrb I have added every line of code of the project to the post (safe for CardView which I think is irrelevant to the issue at hand)

Comment: The reason it is important is this: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I found someone else's `CardView` and put the app together. I see no errors. I get a grid of emoji pairs when it runs. This may be a phantom error. Clean your build folder, delete the apps folder in Derived Data and rebuild it. See if that works.

Comment: Post may be dated, but wondering why using id: \.self would know an error?

Answer (score 1):

I copied pasted your code without modifying  anything, it ran without any error.

That ForEach is not the problem here. If you still face the error, try this:

```
ForEach(viewModel.cards, id: \.id) { }
```

Comment: Honestly I'm way past that point right now, I think it's just the random kinda errors Xcode like to throw sometimes

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented a var id = UUID() on the Card struct, made it conform to Identifiable and removed the id: .self from the ForEach loop. It's valid now.

```
   struct Card: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var isFacedUp: Bool = false
        var isMatched: Bool = false
        
        var content: CardContent
        
    }

    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]) {
        ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
            CardView(card: card)
                .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
```